# Give a reason why $\mathbb Z_4 \times \mathbb Z_2 $ and $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2 $ are not isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism

> Give a reason why $\mathbb Z_4 \times \mathbb Z_2 $ and $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2 $ are not isomorphic

In order for them to be be isomorphic, don't they have to have the same order?

Comment: What is the meaning of your last sentence? Your groups have the same order here.

Comment: Having the same order is necessary, but not sufficient.

Comment: Indeed, $\mathbb Z_4\times\mathbb Z_2$ and $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2$ both have order $8$.

Comment: And notably, neither is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_8$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If two groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ are isomorphic, then they have same same algebraic structure:  orders of elements are preserved; in particular, if $\phi:G_1 \to G_2$ is an isomorphism then $\lvert a \rvert =\lvert \phi(a) \rvert$. Now you can easily see that $\mathbb{Z}_4\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ has an element of order $4$, but $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ has no element of order $4$; in fact, every non-identity element of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ is of order $2$. Therefore, these two groups cannot be isomorphic.

Comment: Please give the reason for (-1)

Answer (score 6):

Hint: can you find an element of order $4$ in any of these groups?

Answer (score 1):

> In order for them to be be isomorphic, don't they have to have the same order?

Yes, but groups of the same order need not be isomorphic!

One of your groups has an element of order $4$ whereas the other does not.

Use the following

> **Lemma:** If $\varphi: G\to H$ is an isomorphism, then for any $g\in G$, the order of $\varphi(g)$ in $H$ is that of $g$ in $G.$

Can you prove this lemma?

*Hint:* It follows from the fact that $\varphi$ takes the identity element $e_G$ of $G$ to that of $H$, and preserves powers, *i.e.*, $\varphi(k^n)=(\varphi (k))^n$ for all integers $n$ and all $k\in G$.

Comment: ok, so they must have the same order and structure must be preserved. How does that work when you compare say $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Q$ under addition lets say. Would this be not isomorphic since $\mathbb Q$ allows fractions and $\mathbb Z$ doesnt?

Comment: @Shaun All nonzero elements of $\mathbb Q$ have infinite order.

Comment: Yes, my bad, @eyeballfrog; thank you!

Comment: @cele Essentially yes. Explicitly, if there were an isomorphism $f: \mathbb Z\rightarrow \mathbb Q$, then we would have $f^{-1}(f(1)/2) + f^{-1}(f(1)/2) = 1$, which is impossible in $\mathbb Z$.